# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NbOAuth2AuthStrategy -> InjectionToken Window];NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Window

Tags: angular, nebular

We are trying to integrate nebular/auth(nebular/theme is already added) in our new angular project for implementing Configuring Google Oauth2. HttpClientModule is also configured in AppModule's imports array.

Getting the above mentioned error while integrating nebular/auth module in a new angualar(Angualar 8.2.9) for implementing Configuring Google Oauth2 Authentication mechanism.

AppModule.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import {
  NbAuthModule,
  NbOAuth2AuthStrategy,
  NbAuthOAuth2JWTToken,
  NbOAuth2ResponseType
} from "@nebular/auth";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NbAuthModule.forRoot({
      strategies: [
        NbOAuth2AuthStrategy.setup({
          name: "google",
          clientId:
            "xxx",
          clientSecret: "xxx",
          authorize: {
            endpoint: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
            responseType: NbOAuth2ResponseType.TOKEN,
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",

            redirectUri: "http://localhost:4201/pages"
          },
          token: {
            class: NbAuthOAuth2JWTToken,
            requireValidToken: false
          }
        })
      ]
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NbAuthService } from "@nebular/auth";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "oauth2";

  constructor(private authService: NbAuthService) {}

  sub() {
    // this.authService.authenticate('google')
  }
}
```

AppComponent.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sign-in with Google</h1>
  <form #login="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sub()">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If everything configured correctly,Login Button should be displayed which takes the user to Google Authentication Page. But showing that error(commented the code in sub() method) How to resolve this? Any version conflicts?

Comment: https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/208

Answer (score 3):

Nebular Auth module requires Theme module to be installed as well.

In your `app.module.ts` add this to the `providers`

```
        providers: [ ..., NbThemeModule.forRoot() ]
```

That should fix the error.